# How to query media file metadata using ffprobe, e.g., track number?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, flac, ffprobe, m4a

I want a single command to retrieve track number (or other metadata) from an audio file using ffprobe.

Comment: https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo

Comment: So, what research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```sh
ffprobe -v error -of csv=s=x:p=0 -show_entries format_tags=track my-file
```

Worked successfully for mp3, m4a and flac formats using `ffprobe version 6.0-full_build-www.gyan.dev`.

Run `ffprobe file` to see all available metadata that you can query by replacing `track` above.

If you want to zero-pad track numbers (`1` -> `01` etc.) and also to turn null tracks into `00`:

```sh
for file in *; do
  printf '%02d\n' "$(ffprobe -v error -of csv=s=x:p=0 -show_entries format_tags=track "$file")"
done
```

And if you want null tracks to become `99`:

```sh
for file in *; do
  printf '%02d\n' "$(ffprobe -v error -of csv=s=x:p=0 -show_entries format_tags=track "$file")" | sed -E 's/00/99/'
done
```